# Remote Hyper-v VMs not being listed

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016

We have a new Windows Server 2016 box in our enviroment and joined to our domain with local VMs running. I can view, connect, and administer these VMs when connected via RDP to Hyper-V host.

The problem is I cannot see these VMs from Hyper-V manager on my local machine. It says `No virtual machines were found on this server.` I can successfully remote into these VMs from my local machine via RDP but don't want to have to have this enabled for each VM or for the Host OS.

I do not have this problem with our Windows Server 2012 R2 Hyper-V host. 
Is there some configuration change from Server 2012 R2 to Server 2016 that might account for this?

I am hoping this is a simple thing I am overlooking. All of the default Hyper-V related firewall rules remain enabled.

EDIT to clarify:

1. I am connecting thru Hyper-V Manager from Windows 10 from a domain admin 
   group user.
2. I Can run the GET-VM powershell command to enumerate the VMs
3. Newley created VMs initially show up but disappear when I refresh that server's list of VMs

I am connecting thru Hyper-V Manager from Windows 10 from a domain admin group user.

Comment: To clarify - you're connecting to a 2016 Server remotely with a 2012 Hyper-V console?

Comment: @MatthewWetmore I am using Hyper-V Manager in Windows 10. The Windows Server 2012 stuff was just for comparison as the 4 VMs I have running on the 2012 server show up on my Windows 10 Hyper-V Manager.

Comment: Can you do other basic things like use PowerShell from your client to the host, like `Get-VM -ComputerName YourHost`?

Comment: `1.` Is the user account you're connecting with a member of the local Administrators or Hyper-V Administrators group on the Windows Server 2016 Hyper-V host? `2.` Is remote management enabled on the Windows Server 2016 Hyper-V host?

Comment: @MatthewWetmore Yes the powershell commands return the instances. Interstingly I added a new VM and it initially shows up but disappeared when I refreshed that server.

Comment: @joeqwerty `1` My user account is a member of the Domain Administrators group but haven't explicitly added any Domain users to local groups on the new server. `2` Yes remote management is enabled

Comment: OK, membership in the Domains Admins group is sufficient as Domain Admins is a member of local Administrators by default. You might want to double check that to be sure though.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you running on your local machine? Do you have the latest version of Hyper-V Manager on your local machine?

Just trying to think through possible causes for you.

Comment: I am connecting via Hyper-v Manager in Windows 10.